# Way to stream payload data from outputstream to HttpRequestBody

Tags: java, jackson, httpclient

In our application, as of now we are making HttpPost requests somewhere like this

```
 HttpResponse makeRequest(String payload) {

     HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
     request.setEntity(new StringEntity(payload));
     //Set headers etc
     return this.httpClient.execute(request);
 }
```

Our payloads are entirely JSON, and we are using JacksonLibrary to handle JSON conversions. (Serialization and Deserialization). During our perf testing, we have observed that Serialising an object into a string (payload) and httpClient taking that payload and making the request is taking a good amount of time. Jackson provides a facility where it can directly write the string to a output stream/writer. (Kind of streaming).

Is there any way that I can configure HttpRequestBase/HttpPost etc to use the response from that outputstream as payload input? 
-> I thought Piping outputstream to inputstream will work, but there is no exposed functionality to set inputstream of HttpRequest as well.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a sensible way to do streaming, but one way to improve it is to use `writeValueAsBytes` and post bytes by httpclient - it will not do unessesary convertion bytes->chars->bytes.

Also you are saying "*Serialising an object into a string (payload) **and** httpClient taking that payload **and** making the request is taking a good amount of time*" - too many things to make any conclusions. You need to investigate more precisely to find exact bottleneck. E.g. probably you just not using jackson properly, e.g. here: https://theartofdev.com/2014/07/20/jackson-objectmapper-performance-pitfall/

Comment: Thanks kan. I have already went through that link and we are using only one instance of ObjectMapper. We are able to stream json as long as its generated in all other cases. (like sending response back to user etc). But we are kind of stuck in only this case. we will try writeValueasBytes and check the perf improvement.